# Niginx location with cache for a specific url with params

Tags: caching, nginx

I'd like to use nginx cache for a specific url only
The url is /ajax/airport and must contain the parameter ?geoloc=1.

Cache is working fine, the only issue I'm facing is to get it working for an url containing the given parameters.

Here is my nginx site.conf file:

```
    server {
          listen 80;
          server_name _;
          server_tokens off;

          location /ajax/airport.php {
             if ($args_geoloc = 1) {
                  proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080/ajax/airport.php;
                  proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                  proxy_cache  my-cache;
                  proxy_cache_valid 300s;
                  #proxy_no_cache $cookie_PHPSESSID;
                  #proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_PHPSESSID;
                  proxy_cache_key         "$scheme$host$request_uri";
                  add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
                  add_header LEM airport;
             }
         }

         location / {
             proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080/; 
             proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
             proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             add_header LEM all;
         }
  }


    server {
          listen 8080;
          .. usual location handeling ...
```

And the error I get:

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.com.conf:8
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [proxy_no_cache](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_no_cache) and [proxy_cache_bypass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_bypass) instead of `if`, testing the value of `$arg_geoloc` (not `$args_geoloc`) with [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) directive.

```
map $arg_geoloc $bypass {
    default    1;
    1          0;
}

server {
    ...
    location /ajax/airport.php {
        ...
        proxy_no_cache $bypass;
        proxy_cache_bypass $bypass;
        ...
        # No need to add /ajax/airport.php in proxy_pass
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    ...
}
```

Nginx also allows to test several parameters with `proxy_no_cache` and `proxy_cache_bypass`. If you need something like that just put the parameters one after another:

```
proxy_no_cache $cookie_PHPSESSID $bypass_cache;
proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_PHPSESSID $bypass_cache;
```

Comment: Actually I'm wondering why we need those 2 servers (one on :80 the other in :8080). Isn't it possible to use one server (:80) and add the '/ajax/airport' location over there? Is the proxy_pass required for the proxy_cache to work? Thanks

Comment: @LEM01 I didn't notice that you proxy_passed to another Nginx server. That is indeed quite odd. Yes, proxy_pass is required if you want to cache something with the proxy module, but you can proxy_pass directly to your backend.

Comment: Ok so if proxy pass is required I have to setup 2 servers like I did, right? Actually I just found out about fastcgi_cache which seem to be a better fit to my requirements as I don't have actual need of routing to another server.